# Flex Box - 3 column - align top

Tags: css, flexbox

I am having difficulty top aligning my 3 columns with multiple "rows". If I use the CSS property `align-items: flex-end;` I get the correct results, but elements are aligned at the bottom. If I try `align-items: flex-start;` nothing happens.

In the fiddle I would like the red block to move up so it is right bellow the Purple Heading.

[image]

Please see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0eqLf321/30/)

Any help would be great!

Comment: flex draws row by rows or columns by columns. flex children do not span through cols or rows :( Grid can but spanning values are to be set. Basicly , grid will behave like flex at first approach: https://jsfiddle.net/0eqLf321/33/ but you can set an element spanning through few rows or columns https://jsfiddle.net/0eqLf321/34/

Comment: Please try `align-items: stretch;`

Comment: @G-Cyr I would like to use flex-box or something with more browser support. But it sounds like the result I want is not possible with flex-box. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This is not how flex works indeed ;) , see this tutorial to find out use and possibilities https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/  and this other one about grid https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ both are grid system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change html structure a little bit, if you want to make your task. I propose two versions to solve this issue. You can see it on the Fiddle.

Fiddle 1 - https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewKovalchuk/c6o4gdmh/

```
.categories {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.categories > ul {
  margin: 0;
  width: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

Fiddle 2 - https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewKovalchuk/q6jt2d8h/

```
.categories {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.categories .category {
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.category > ul {  
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. But I wanted to keep the HTML the same. I actually found another solution that worked for me. The `break-inside: avoid;` property was key for me. https://jsfiddle.net/nq7gz12b/13/

Answer (score 0):

set flex-direction: column and give it a fixed height.

```
height: 400px;
flex-direction: column;
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0eqLf321/40/

Comment: I would like to keep the 3 column layout. Thanks!

Comment: Give height 300px then. Check if this works for you.